# Tensorflow tf.sigmoid() returning an array rather than a scalar

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a simple logistic regression model in tensorflow with only one class.  However, for some reason, the tf.sigmoid function is returning an array type rather than a scalar.

The type of value returned from the cost function is an np.ndarray()

The shape is (3390,2)

I can't figure out why the tf.sigmoid function would return an array type rather than a scalar...
any help appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import model_selection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import sys

sns.set(style='white')
sns.set(style='whitegrid',color_codes=True)



bank_data = pd.read_csv('data/bank.csv',header=0,delimiter = ';')
bank_data = bank_data.dropna()

bank_data.drop(bank_data.columns[[0,3,8,9,10,11,12,13]],axis=1,inplace=True)
data_set = pd.get_dummies(bank_data,columns = ['job','marital','default','housing','loan','poutcome'])
data_set.drop(data_set.columns[[14,27]],axis=1,inplace=True)
data_set_y = data_set['y']
data_set_y = data_set_y.replace(('yes','no'),(1.0,0.0))

data_set_X = data_set.drop(['y'],axis=1)
num_samples = data_set.shape[0]
num_features = data_set_X.shape[1]
num_labels = 1


X = tf.placeholder('float',[None,num_features])
y = tf.placeholder('float',[None,num_labels])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_features,2]),dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]),dtype=tf.float32)

train_X,test_X,train_y,test_y = model_selection.train_test_split(data_set_X,data_set_y,random_state=0)
train_y = np.reshape(train_y,(-1,1))

prediction = tf.add(tf.matmul(X,W),b)
cost = tf.sigmoid(prediction)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cost)
num_epochs = 1000


print ('Shape of train_y is: ',train_y.shape)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        _,l = sess.run([optimizer,cost],feed_dict = {X: train_X, y: train_y})
        if epoch % 50 == 0:
            print (type(l))
            print (l.shape)
            print (l)
```

Answer (score 0):

[sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) is a function defined on scalars.

`tf.sigmoid` computes the sigmoid on each element of the input tensor (see [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sigmoid)), so the output will have the same shape as the input.

What do you expect the sigmoid of a 3390x2 matrix to be? Depending on the answer to that, you might want to apply some reductions to create a meaningful scalar out of `predictions` and then apply sigmoid to that, or use a loss function such as [`tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) or other functions in [`tf.losses`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sigmoid:

> tf.sigmoid

```
sigmoid(
    x,
    name=None
)
```

> Computes sigmoid of x element-wise.

Your `prediction` in this case is likely not a scalar - examine `prediction.shape` to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you want to classify between two classes, you only need one pre-activation to be supplied to the activation function, because the sigmoid function is 1/(1+exp(-x)) as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

In your code for example, I think the second dimension of W should be 1 instead of 2. The first dimension of l should be the number of records in your data.

If you want to do a multinomial classification rather than this binary case. Your should use a softmax activation function instead of sigmoid. In your case, instead of changing the dimension of W, replacing your activation to tf.nn.softmax should also work.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax